# $\{p \in [1, \infty]: f \in L^p\}$ is an interval?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

I understood the proof but why does this imply that $\{p \in [1, \infty]: f \in L^p\}$ is an interval?

Answer (score 2):

The inequality implies that if $f\in L^p$ and $f\in L^q$ for $p<q$, then $f\in L^r$ for all $p<r<q$. This implies that the set is an interval.